# Почему кнопка по ширине и высоте больше, чем задано?

Tags: html, css

Почему кнопка по ширине и высоте получается больше, чем задано?

Был применен `box-sizing: border-box;`.

И из-за этого кнопка "заезжает" за экран.

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/Van245/pen/MWKRerp)

```css
.button a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 195px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="/adventures">adventures</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае Вы задаете pading(и) с обоих сторон текста и Вам не нужно задавать width и height отдельно для Вашей кнопки. Тогда ее высота будет складываться из размера шрифта и отступов по вертикали, а ширина исходя из длинны текста и его отступов по горизонтали. Границы так же стоит учитывать при их наличии.

Когда Вы задаете дополнительный width и/или height, в случае если, например, width больше чем длинна текста, его отступов и границ, то размер Вашей кнопки будет равен заданному значению width, если же меньше, то дальше все зависит от конкретного браузера и вероятность того что кнопка окажется не того размера крайне вероятна.

Поскольку `<a>` это inline элемент, то он выравнивался относительно уровня начала самого текста. Именно поэтому он "заезжал под экран", и в том числе поскольку стили для его родительского блока так же отсутствовали.

Для того что бы это исправить достаточно превратить его в блочный элемент, добавив ему свойство `display` со значением `block` или `inline-block`.

```css
.button a {
  display: inline-block; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="/adventures">adventures</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Получается, что делая кнопку, лучше вообще не указывать ее размеры (width/height)? Либо для кнопки лучше всего указывать минимальные высоту и ширину (если например будет добавляться другой текст). Просто странно, что кнопка получается больше, если все данные были взяты четко из макета.

Comment: Понятно, большое спасибо))